# OSError input/output error when writing to mounted filesystem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mount, fuse, gcsfuse

I have created Google Cloud Storage Bucket and mounted it to my VM using:
`gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount/point`
When I type `df -H` its listed as mounted filesystem.
I have the following issue:

If I upload file to the bucket using the GCP web console I can see it from the VM. If I try to create a directory however from the VM to the mounted file system `mkdir /path/to/mount/point/test` it says:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/path/to/mount/point/test’: Input/output error
```

Comment: I think it permission problem , see https://serverfault.com/questions/750640/permission-errors-using-gcsfuse-as-nonroot-user-on-google-compute-instance

Comment: In the post they get "Permission denied" while I get Input/output error. I also think it might be because of permissions, but cannot figure out why. I mount it with "gcsfuse -o allow_other -file-mode=777 -dir-mode=777 XXX /var/data" and when I "stat /var/data" it seems to be 777 indeed. The bucket permissions in the GCP console are set to "object-level and bucket-level permissions" as by default and I have given user project-XXX@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com Storage Owner permissions. Still, I can list, but I cannot write data to the mounted filesystem.

Comment: try to add --debug_gcs --debug_fuse  after gcsfuse to get more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause. I enabled the debug options as others suggested. Thank you. Unfortunately the logs did not tell me much. Fortunately I had one more VM and I tested there and it worked fine (mount + read/write to bucket). I understood its not the permissions on the bucket side. The VM was created with "Allow default access" which gives readonly to "Storage". I granted read/write to store. One can specify also "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" although its better not to grant all permissions if you do not need them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following command,and it will show more information.

```
gcsfuse --foreground --debug_gcs --debug_http \
        --debug_fuse --debug_invariants \
        --key-file=/src/gcloud_service_account.json \
        my-bucket /path/to/mount/point
```

You might see such error message

```
"code": 403, "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage JSON API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
```

If so , you need to enable this API for this instance.