# mounting bucket with fstab not working NEWBIE

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, centos7, gcsfuse, fstab

I'm new on GCP and on linux and I try to mount a bucket on my centos instance using gcsfuse.

I tried with a script running at boot but it was not working so I tried with fstab (peoples told me it is much better)

But I got this error when I tried to ls my mounted point :

> ls: reading directory .: Input/output error

here is my fstab file :

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Mar 26 23:07:36 2019
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under'/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=de2d3dce-cce3-47a8-a0fa-5bfe54e611ab /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
mybucket /mount/to/point gcsfuse rw,allow_other,uid=1001,gid=1001
```

According : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The question you are asking seems to be more sysadmin related and will be addressed better in Serverfault. Please ask this question on Serverfault.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382783/oserror-input-output-error-when-writing-to-mounted-filesystem/55397916#55397916

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSError input/output error when writing to mounted filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382783/oserror-input-output-error-when-writing-to-mounted-filesystem)

Comment: @howie read all the question I'm using FSTAB. But since a few reboot I noticed that I got this error for 3-5 minutes and then works perfecly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I just had to wait 2 minutes due to google auth granting my key. Basically it works